# cfldap add member to exchange distribution list

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

I've been going through a lot of the documentation online about managing users in Exchange distribution lists with cfldap. I'm wanting to pass the distribution list and member attributes as form variables from cfldap queryies but I'm getting a little confused on syntax. The cfldap queries that display the distribution lists and users or be added or removed work, where I'm getting tripped up is passing those form variables to the cfldap that modifies the list.

My cfldap query that displays the distribution lists for the user to select, uses name as the attribute. In the cfldap modify action, I'd pass that attribute as a form variable for the distribution list to be modified as:

dn="CN=#form.Name#,CN=Users,dc=domain, dc=org" (all of our distribution lists are located here, don't ask me why, just the way it is.)

Then the member to be added or deleted would be passed to the same cfldap action as another form variable:

attributes="mail=#form.email#"

Which would be the email address of the users selected.

Am I on the right track with this? In addition to being a ColdFusion noob, I'm an ldap noob as well. Any links to documentation on "cfldap For Dummies" would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried and what result did you get?

Comment: Seconded what Brad said. Read this lot: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html (including links), then pls revise your question.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I'm working on adding code to catch the error(s) I'm getting. For some reason, I've never been able to get our ColdFusion 9 test server to process coldfusion pages so I don't get the detailed error information you get when you run the pages directly on the server. All I get now is a blank screen on my workstation when the code fails. I'm using cftry and cfcatch I just need to figure out how to output the ldap error. I'll post when I have more detailed information for you. Thanks.

Comment: Gotta love cfcatch.message!! Got what I needed. Thanks again.